# Size of class with virtual keyword and character in it

Tags: c++, c++11

I ran the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{  
    char c;

    public:

        virtual ~Base()
        {
        }
};

int main()
{   
  cout << sizeof(Base) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

1) The size is 4 (for vptr) + 1(for char). But the result is 8. Why is it so ?

2) I replaced char with a int variable, still the output is 8. Can someone explain me what has caused this issue?

Comment: Classes have padding added to them so they'll align better. There are many similar questions to this if you search.

Answer (score 3):

It's down to padding. The compiler has packed your class to a multiple of 4 bytes.